# installing getnonfreefonts in VirtualBox - Unknown option error

Tags: fonts, installing, installing-fonts, technical-environment

I am have trouble installing the nonfreefonts. When I execute `getnonfreefonts -sys -a` I get `Unknown option: y`. If I run for example `getnonfreefonts -user --version` I get `Unknown option: e`.

I am almost certain I used the same steps to install the fonts before, but this time I am doing it in a virtual machine - which shouldn't make a difference, but you never know...

My full setup:

- VirtualBox 5.1.26
- Windows 8.1 64 bit as host
- Linux Mint 17.2 64 bit as guest
- GNU bash, Version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- TeX Live 2017
- getnonfreefonts, revision 2017-06-02

Any ideas what might cause the error? Am I using the tool wrong or does the bash works incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe try with`getnonfreefonts --user --version`

Comment: and `getnonfreefonts --sys -a` or `getnonfreefonts --sys --all`

Comment: In general, a single hyphen is used only for a short, one-letter option and a double hyphen for long, multi-letter option names. If you write `-sys`, this will be interpreted as if you'd written `-s -y -s`. But `-y` is not recognised. Similarly `-user` is `-u -s -e -r` but `-e` is not recognised (and `-s` probably trumps `-u` here).

Comment: @samcarter Good spot. You should answer. Maybe include the explanation?

Comment: @cfr Your comment explains the problem very nicely - it would be a waste of time if I tried to write something  - can you please convert it in an answer?

Comment: I feel so dumb… it is one of those issues where you should take a step back and watch over it after you took a break. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Nah. Don't feel dumb. It is always easier to see other people's mistakes than your own :(.

Answer (score 3):

This is [samcarter's spot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388015/installing-getnonfreefonts-in-virtualbox-unknown-option-error?noredirect=1#comment962160_388015), but the spotter insists it is better to convert my explanation to an answer.

You need, for example,

```
getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

or

```
getnonfreefonts --sys --all
```

as samcarter said. The reason for this is that `getnonfreefonts` follows the standard shell convention that a single hyphen indicates one or more short, one-letter option(s), while a double hyphen is used for a single, multi-letter option.

If you write `-sys`, this will be interpreted as if you'd written `-s -y -s`. But `-y` is not a recognised option, as the error tells you. Similarly `-user` means `-u -s -e -r` but `-e` is not recognised, as the other error tells you. Moreover, in this latter case, `-s` probably trumps `-u`.

The errors are not entirely clear because the usage information produced by `--help` is incomplete, in that it does not list all short-form options recognised by the command. Looking in the script, `-s` is an undocumented alternative for `--sys` and `-u` for `--user`. This is why the errors do not complain about `-s` and `-u` being unrecognised (rather than `-y` and `-e`), as we might have naïvely expected from the usage listing of options.